# use usb install disk for my files

Tags: software-installation

USB Install Disk: 16GiB SanDisk

Directories on USB Install Disk are as follows:

1. Ubuntu 19.10 amd64 Partition 1 2.5 GB ISO 9660
2. Can not read it all however ... Ubuntu 19. Partition 2 4.1 MB FAT
3. Casper rw Partiton 3 13 GB Ext4

Do I need the entire disk or can I place some of my own files on the USB?

Thank you;

Sherman

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of that SanDisk USB is to boot up a computer, and install Linux on it.

Turn off the computer, put in the USB drive, and turn the computer on.  You might automatically get a boot menu to select the USB drive, or it might run the program on the drive and bring up the Linux install menu.  If neither of these things happen (you get normal Windows booting up, etc.) then turn the computer off again, and press F12 repeatedly just after powering up to get a boot menu, and then choose to boot from the USB on the menu that comes up.  If it still doesn't work, you need to research how to set up booting from USB on that particular computer.

The ISO that's on there could be burnt to a DVD, and then you can boot up with the DVD in the drive, but that isn't what it was designed for.  You could burn a DVD with that ISO from inside Windows.